# Estimate for $\int_0^t\frac{e^{\alpha s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}ds$ like $\int_0^t\frac{e^{\alpha s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}ds \le \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Does an estimate for $$\int_0^t\frac{e^{\alpha s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}ds$$ like $$\int_0^t\frac{e^{\alpha s}}{s^{\frac{1}{2}}}ds \le \frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha^p},$$  ($p \in \mathbb{R}_+$) hold?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\alpha>0$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{s\alpha}}{\sqrt{s}}\,ds \stackrel{s\mapsto t-s}{=} e^{t\alpha}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{ds}{e^{s\alpha}\sqrt{t-s}}\,dt \stackrel{s\mapsto t u}{=}\sqrt{t}\,e^{t\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{e^{ut\alpha}\sqrt{1-u}}$$
that trivially is $\leq 2\sqrt{t}\,e^{t\alpha}$.
 On the other hand such integral can be computed in terms of the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function):
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{s\alpha}}{\sqrt{s}}\,ds = e^{t\alpha}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\cdot F(\sqrt{\alpha t})\tag{1} $$
hence you may take $p=\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$ since the maximum value of $2\cdot F(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not much larger than $1$ (it is $\approx 1.0821$).

Comment: Is $F$ bounded above independently of $t$? I need an estimate exactly of the type $\frac{e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha^p}$.

Comment: @Riku: yes, answer updated.

Comment: @Riku: in the original problem, is something known about $t,\alpha$ or $\alpha t$? The inequality can be improved if some of them is large.

Comment: Thanks. That's nice! How did you get that the maximum value of $F$? $\alpha$ may be taken large.

Comment: @Riku: I performed a numerical computation through Mathematica.

Comment: D: You should've said you took the derivative with respect to $x$ and found where $F'(x)=0$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: that leads to a trascendental equation, so Newton's method is involved.